# Changing the css style of child element of body cause triggering window resize event in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `ul`element "dropdown-menu-ap" appended to the body of the document.

When I change the CSS style specifically left and top, it triggers the window resize event which I am listening to for other purposes. This happens only for chrome browser.

Please share if anyone have any idea about what is the real cause of the window resize for this scenario?

The screenshot of html is shown below:

[Click to see the Html Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfn9z.jpg)

The code snippet is shown below:

```
$dd.css({
 top: topval,
 left: left
 })
var autoH = $dd.height();
```

The css style used by the element is shown below:

```
.dropdown-menu-ap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 16.5em;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #3C4d4c;
  border: 1px solid #637271;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0.3em 0.3em 0.7em rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 84% !important;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif  !important;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #B9B9B9  !important;
}
```

Comment: How is the element positioned?  Can you post the css?  It could be that it's affecting the position of some other element and thus causing a resize when you move it.

Comment: Please don't post images of code. They're useless... read [ask]

Comment: There is not enough information here to be helpful. Can you include the code that sets up the `window.resize` handler, as well as the code that defines `$dd` and the relevant markup?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt get the exact fix for the problem. But to avoid unnecessary window resize event, compare the previous window width and height and proceed the window resize event if width or height differs. This is only a workaround solution.

private previousWindowWidth = 0;
 private previousWindowHeight = 0;

private onWindowResize(): void {

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHt = window.innerHeight;
if (previousWindowWidth  === windowWidth && previousWindowHeight === 
    windowHt ) {
    return;
 }

previousWindowWidth = windowWidth ;
previousWindowHeight = windowHt ;

// continue with other operations
..................................
}
```